# Pedir palabras en un prompt, eliminar las repetidas y ordenarlas de la Z a la A con Set()

Tags: javascript, set, prompt

Estoy tratando de realizar un prompt que se repita hasta que no se le introduzca nada en su interior o se cancele, mientras tanto podremos seguir escribiendo palabras y aceptando. Con las palabras de nuestro prompt las almacenaremos en un set y a continuación eliminaremos las repetidas, y las sobrantes las ordenaremos por orden alfabético inverso, con un sort de la "z" a la "a".

Este es el codigo que he tratado de hacer yo pero no funciona correctamente.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda ya que soy novata en JS.

```js
const mySet = new Set();
  function agregar(palabra) {
    let contar = 1;

    let escribir = mySet.add(palabra); 
    mySet.add(palabra); 
  }

  while (true) {
    let palabra = window.prompt('Escribe algo:');
    if (!palabra) {
      break;
    }
    agregar(palabra);
  }
  console.log(mySet);
  Array.from(mySet).sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a > b) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (b > a) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
```

Estoy tratando de ordenar `mySet.add(palabra);` de la Z a la A pero no logro hacerlo correctamente ya que he probado a colocar:

```
let ordenar= mySet.sort("z","a");
console.log(ordenar);
```

pero no hay manera de que funcione me da error, he entrado en [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Set)

Pero solo sale como sería si quisiera ordenarlo por ejemplo:

```
for (let item of mySet.values()) console.log(item);
```

como seria para ordenarlo a la inversa??

Comment: he tratado de crear una variable y asignarle el mySet.sort("z","a") pero me dice error, a que te refieres exactamente?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: mySet.reverse is not a function esto me dice, igual con el sort como colocarias el reverse o el sort  a un set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He tardado unos dias en poder subir la respuesta final, pero el resultado fue el siguiente, para ordenar las palabras de a la A la Z, terminé usando el método de la burbuja también conocido como bubble sort, que mediante un `for` cambia la posición de los arrays en este caso para ordenarlos como requería el ejercicio.

```
    const mySet = new Set();
      function agregar(palabra) {
        let contar = 1;
    
        let escribir = mySet.add(palabra); 
        mySet.add(palabra); 
      }
    
      while (true) {
        let palabra = window.prompt('Escribe algo:');
        if (!palabra) {
          break;
        }
        agregar(palabra);
      }
      const myArr = Array.from(mySet);
  let bubbleSort = (myArr) => {
    let len = myArr.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        if (myArr[j] < myArr[j + 1]) {
          let tmp = myArr[j];
          myArr[j] = myArr[j + 1];
          myArr[j + 1] = tmp;
        }
      }
    }
    return myArr;
  };
  console.log(bubbleSort(Array.from(mySet)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, de manera final, he conseguido esto para ordenar tu SET.

```
Array.from(mySet).sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a > b) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (b > a) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

El output obtenido, es el deseado ahora.

Comment: voy a revisarlo :) el array se colocaria debajo donde estaba el console log ? se añadiria de alguna forma al console.log?

Comment: nose si estoy colocando alguna cosa mal pero aceptr y cancelar ya no responden igual y sale ordenado de la a la z en vez de alreves

Comment: listo, ya lo he pegado :)

Comment: no entiendo entonces que podría estar sucediendo, lo unico que podría tener diferente es que todo esta dentro de una función que es el ejercicio en si que es invocado desde otro archivo, pero no he pensado que esto fuera relevante

Comment: si si esta la funcion que engloba el ejercicio en si, en plan practica8{ y aqui dentro todo el codigo}

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema proviene de las asignaciones.

1. Cuando haces

```
let escribir = mySet.add(palabra);
```

Asignas el objeto mySet con la palabra agregada a la variable escribir. Ver [Set prototype Add()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Set/add)

Luego haces una suma adicionando 1 a escribir. **Es un error de tipos** de modo que contar no alcanza el valor 2 como tu esperas.

```
<!-- lang: javascript -->
if (escribir) {
  // esto no funciona porque escribir es un Set
  contar = escribir + 1; 
  if (contar >= 2) {
    mySet.delete(palabra);
  }
}
```

Adicionalmente, como deseas no incluir repeticiones debes usar el método has() en lugar del delete que estabas intentando dónde señale el error

```
function agregar(palabra) {
    // verificas que la palabra no haya sido asignada con anterioridad
    if(!mySet.has(palabra){
       // se puede agregar sin necesidad de asignar a otra variable
       mySet.add(palabra);
    } // en otro caso sigues derecho en silencio
}
```

Como aún no has ordenado te sugiero aplicar una burbuja.
Hasta aquí, se resuelven los problemas que identifiqué en tu código.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias !!! ya he elminado y colocado la prte del codigo en su lugar :)

Comment: un gusto @azucarilla